# Expectation of a joint distribution but over only one variable

Tags: probability, integration, expected-value

Have I missed anything here. I want to make sure that I can safely marginalize over one of the variables in the joint distribution even if they are not independent.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}_{p(X, Y)}[XX^\top] &= \iint_{X, Y} p(X | Y)p(Y) XX^\top dXdY \\
&= \int_{X} p(X) XX^\top dX\\
&= \mathbb{E}_{p(X)}[XX^\top]
\end{aligned}
$$

Is this correct? Or have I forgotten something somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of marginalizing joint probability density function is to get knowledge(form of the distribution) about each variable that makes up that joint probability density function.

However, if the variables that makes up the join distribution are independent then their joint probability density function can be written as the product of the marginal probability density function of each of the random variable that makes up the joint distribution.

Since, In your case we are only finding the expectation of the function of random variable X only it is same as calculating expectation using the marginal probability density function of random variable X.